# Any better method for evaluating this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

[image: limit method]

If l dont apply the limit earlier and replace x(tan(x))^2 with x^3, then l will have to keep applying L'hospital rule several times to get the answer -1/2. Is this method correct and are there any better methods to solve this limit.

Comment: Please spare us such inserted handwritten drafts.

Comment: The method is fine. Working it out with Taylor developments will be a little simpler.

Comment: You started off correctly. After applying L'Hospital's Rule once you need to use a bit of algebra and reduce your expression to $$\frac{(1-x)(\sin x+\cos x) - 1}{3x^2}$$ Do some algebra and calculate the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want another method, you could consider Taylor expansion.

Since, close to $x=0$, $\tan(x)\sim x$, the denominator is $\sim x^3$ and so, you need to combine series at least up to $O(x^3)$.

Doing it combining the Taylor series of the different pieces, we have
$$\frac{1+\sin (x)-\cos (x)+\log (1-x)}{x \tan^2(x)}=\frac{-\frac{x^3}{2}+O\left(x^4\right) } {x^3+O\left(x^4\right) }=-\frac 12+O\left(x\right)$$ and this is your limit.

But, at least four your curiosity, use one more term in each expansion to get
$$\frac{1+\sin (x)-\cos (x)+\log (1-x)}{x \tan^2(x)}=\frac{-\frac{x^3}{2}-\frac{7 x^4}{24}+O\left(x^5\right) } {x^3+O\left(x^5\right) }$$ and long division would give
$$\frac{1+\sin (x)-\cos (x)+\log (1-x)}{x \tan^2(x)}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{7}{24}x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which, for sure, still shows the limit but also how it is approached.